# Optimal location of block with drag&drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

[codepen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7DFV.png)

I have 2 areas. I need to grab blocks from first area and drop them in the second area. I did it with drag&drop technology. But here I have some problems. In the second area they are not optimally located. How would I solve this problem? see my codepen link above.
https://codepen.io/IlyaCheredov1/full/VwwYVya

Comment: this is a classic 2d bin packing problem. google and SO should be full of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I founded this tiny Library https://mapbox.github.io/potpack/